# entity framework only populating child on first item

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

When using eager loading to get child elements from the database, only the first Enrollment record on customer gets the OrderMembers populated. All subsequent Enrollment records has the Order on it, but no OrderMembers populated.

So I have a customer that has 3 enrollments, each having an order, and the order having multiple people associated with it. I have confirmed the information in the database and have ran the query that gets generated from entity framework, and the data is being returned for OrderMembers. But OrderMembers only gets populated for the first enrollment being returned. The other two enrollments only have the order with no OrderMembrs.

Include statement:

```
DbContext.Customers.Include(x => x.Enrollments.Select(order => order.OrderSnapshot).Select(p =>p.OrderMembers)
```

Class structure:

```
public class Customers
{
    public IList<Enrollment> Enrollments {get; set;}
}

public class Enrollment
{
    public OrderSnapshot Order {get; set;}
}

public class OrderSnapshot
{
    public IList<Persons> OrderMembers {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have the right syntax. It should be

```
DbContext.Customers.Include(x => x.Enrollments.Select(order => order.OrderSnapshot.OrderMembers))
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx